What is the best way to emulate a tube EQ in DSP?
What is the best way to do it? Quite a noob question but could you design a linear filter then add a mask with the non-linearities of the tube (harmonic distortion, saturation, noise)?
I'm sure there are other ways to do it but I don't have much knowledge in dsp

On DSP Robotics Forums you can find schema for Tube stage emulation (you need to install Flow Stone (demo) to study the schema).

Will Pirkle - Designing Audio Effect Plugins in C++: For AAX, AU, and VST3 with DSP Theory. Designing Audio FX Plugins 2nd Edition (see Downloads menu).

It's actually a very difficult question to answer.  Do you mean like a Pultec EQP-1A?  What you need to emulate it, is to get a good schematic and learn how the separate stages or sections are working.  Then you have to model the non-linear devices (the vacuum tubes and the hysteresis in the transformers) along with linear devices that have storage (like capacitors and inductors).
There are mathematical relationships between the different terminals of these component parts and there are Kirchoff's laws for the circuit.  From that you have differential equations with some non-linear expressions that you get from the tube curves and from the transformer behavior.
Then you have to express these differential equations as discrete-time difference equations.  The simplest way I know of is the Euler Forward method.  You'll probably want a sample rate that's good and high, like 96 kHz, perhaps 192 kHz, so your difference equations match the continuous-time differential equations faithfully.
This shit ain't easy.  There are plug-ins and other products doing it.

High sample rate also helps to mitigate aliasing. A hard clipper generates A LOT of harmonics that can seep out of band

I have a somewhat noob question: is there a way to model this using, for example, digital filters or non-linear filters? Could we model the equalization curve and then the harmonics and other non-linearities? Or, is the best way to approach this through differential equations and circuit modeling?
